# not able to show and hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <ol class="novice">
<li>
    <p class="glava">HTML</p>
    <div class="vsebina">
        <p>Hyper Text Markup Language (slovensko jezik za označevanje nadbesedila...</p>
    </div>

</li>
<li>
    <p class="glava">CSS</p>
    <div class="vsebina">
        <p>Cascading Style Sheets (kratica CSS) so predloge, ki določajo izgled ...</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

When I click on the `p class="glava"` I want that the specific `div` that is located in this `li` is shown(`.show()`) and all the others(`div`s) are hidden. I have around ten `li`.

```
$("p.glava").click(function () {
    $(something).show();
    //$(everything else ).hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerous ways to traverse to isolate specific instance. All start with `this` being the element instance of that class that was clicked

```
$("p.glava").click(function () {
   $('.vsebina').hide();

   $(this).parent().find('.vsebina').show()
   // or
   $(this).next('.vsebina').show()  
   // or
   $(this).siblings('.vsebina').show()  
}) ;
```

References

1. [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
2. [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
3. [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
4. [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Answer (score 2):

With Slide Toggle animation

```
$(".glava").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.vsebina').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

With Fade Toggle animation

```
$(".glava").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.vsebina').fadeToggle('slow');
});
```

And just to hide

```
$(".glava").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.vsebina').hide();
});
```